# JavaScript language extensions with function calls lacking parenthesis - are they possible?

Tags: javascript, extending, language-extension

Is it possible, by any means, to do something like this:

```
function A() {
    var Loaded = 'loaded';
    raise Loaded;
}
function A_raise(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
}
A.prototype.constructor = A;
A.prototype.raise = A_raise;
```

The critical part being the line:

```
raise Loaded;
```

Comment: If it's a critical part, perhaps you could tell us what you mean by `raise` (as that's not a JavaScript keyword). Did you mean `throw`? If not, what *do* you mean?

Comment: If you don't like the _messy_ JavaScript syntax you could look at languages that compile to JavaScript like CoffeeScript.

Comment: It was just an example, the goal would be to create a new keyword named "raise" that passes a parameter to A_raise.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get a parentheses-less function call in JavaScript is to define a setter/getter property, or to override one of the special methods : `toString` or `valueOf`.  In neither case do you have really good control over the parameter that gets passed to the call.

```
function C() {}
C.prototype.valueOf = function () { alert("valueOf called"); };
var c = new C();
// No parentheses
+c;
```

You can invoke a constructor without parentheses, but again, cannot pass arguments.

```
function f() { alert("f"); }
// No parentheses
new f
```

---

One reason you can't is semicolon insertion.

```
f()
```

is a function call, as is

```
f
()
```

and

```
if
(x) { }
```

is a valid conditional because `if` is a core part of the language but if you could just drop the parentheses from a function call then semicolon-insertion would have to treat code like

```
var x = raise

y
```

as a variable initialized to the result of calling a function.

---

Since you asked about language extensions, Chapter 16 of the EcmaScript specification says that interpreters are allowed to add to the grammar of the language,

> An implementation may extend program syntax and regular expression pattern or flag syntax. To permit this, all operations (such as calling eval, using a regular expression literal, or using the Function or RegExp constructor) that are allowed to throw SyntaxError are permitted to exhibit implementation-defined behaviour instead of throwing SyntaxError when they encounter an implementation-defined extension to the program syntax or regular expression pattern or flag syntax.

so since

```
 raise foo
```

is not a valid expression or statement in the language, they could allow it, but they could not do so in a way that changes the meaning of

```
 raise
 foo
```

which must have the same meaning as

```
 raise;
 foo
```

so the interpreter would have to make `raise` a new [restricted production](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9.1) which is problematic because of the verbiage:

> The following are the only restricted productions in the grammar:

That is probably meant to be non-normative, but it is not explicitly so.

Comment: I realize trying to add a new keyword to a scripting language is a bit to ask, so I don't mind a hack of a way to do it, but with properties aren't you limited to using an equal sign?  I'd really like to avoid using parenthesis or any symbols - the goal is "raise Loading;"

Comment: @CoryG: Not with the current JavaScript, no. A property getter *almost* works (you don't need an `=`), but you can't pass an argument into it (and it would have to be `this.raise Loading;` at which point, really, you may as well throw parens at it).

Comment: How do you reduce it to "this.raise Loading"?  I've been able to get it down to "raise(Loading);" or "raise = Loading;" but nothing but a space between "raise" and "Loading" is where I have issues.

Comment: @CoryG, there's no way.  The phrase `raise Loading` is simply not a valid JS expression, so it won't make it past the parser.

Comment: I'm inquiring to the "this.raise Loading;" that T.J. Crowder cited in his comment.

Comment: @CoryG, `this.raise Loading;` is also not a valid expression.  Please see my edit re language extensions.

Comment: @CoryG, you might be able to get `Loading in this.raise` to do what you want by abusing [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) but I think that automatically coerces the argument to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define new statements in JavaScript, so you can't actually create the syntax you show in `A`.

**Edit**: From your comment on the question, it's clear you're looking to define a new statement/keyword. No, you can't do that.

---

**Original answer**:

Is your goal inside the `A` constructor to *call* the `A_raise` function? If so, you're *really* close. Just change:

```
raise Loaded;
```

to

```
this.raise(Loaded);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/evuzab/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/evuzab/1/edit)

Within the call to a constructor function via the `new` keyword, `this` is the newly-constructed object, which has already received its prototype from the constructor function's `prototype` property. So `this` will have `raise` on it (via its prototype), and `raise` will refer to the `A_raise` function.

But again, you need the parens (and the `this.`).

Comment: Sorry, I probably left too much of the detail in the title of the post - the goal is to create a new keyword named "raise" that avoids the need to use "this." or parenthesis.

Comment: @CoryG: Yeah, just saw the comment on the question and updated. I'm afraid you can't do that, no.